# is it possible to change firefox OS' native UI with your own?

Tags: web-applications, gecko, firefox-os

Is it possible to overwrite firefox OS native apps with your own apps, like building your own contact list, messages app, phone-app, etc?

Also: is it perhaps even possible (at least in theory) to make your own firefoxOS built and change the native OS UI entirely with your own (javascript&html&css) files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want something that you can release on the Firefox OS Marketplace, it won't be possible. If it's for a personal use or something you want to deploy on devices yourself, you can hack gaia as you wrote, and create your own version of Firefox OS. Since you want to create phone or message app equivalents, you will need [WebAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI) that are just available for certify applications (like the Telephony or WebSMS API), so API only the OS or OEM can use: the only exception is if you are doing your own build of Firefox OS.

As for the second questions, you answered it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question since I didn't quite catch what the term [Gaia](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia) meant before asking the question.

> Gaia is a HTML5-based Phone UI for the Boot 2 Gecko Project.

..which basically contains all the basic apps and the native UI of the phone.
And mozilla published an article about [Hacking Gaia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Gaia/Hacking) so I'll probably be able to do both the things I asked for if I follow that tutorial.